# How to not compile parts of CMakeLists.txt using cmd line parameters?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMake 3.10.2 and have this in place in one of my target CMakeLists.txt files....

```
target_compile_definitions(mytarget PUBLIC USE_MY=${USE_MY})
```

I can then make use of parameters on the command line such as -DUSE_MY=0 so that I can put stuff like this in my c++ files:

```
#ifdef USE_MY
   // code left out
#endif
```

However, I'd also like to be able to leave out files in CMakeLists.txt from compiling.

```
set(my_sources
    filea.cpp
    fileb.cpp
    filec.cpp (how would I leave out filec.cpp?)
)
```

And in my top level CMakeLists.txt, leave out an entire library.

```
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/liba)
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libb) (how to leave out this lib?)
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libc
```

So I'd like to leave out certain files and targets from compiling as well. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: You can append to `my_sources` to add additional sources depending on your CMake variables.

Comment: if (USE_MY) add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libb) endif() the syntax is here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html

Comment: @drescherjm - doing that, I get ... CMake Error at src/targetA/CMakeLists.txt:95 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    if
    
    
target_link_libraries(targetA
    ${my_liba}
if (USE_MY)
    ${my_libb}
endif()
    ${my_liibc}}
)

Comment: @drescherjm - so, I just use seperate target_link_libraries() within an if, elseif. If you make is an answer, I'll check it.

Comment: @Ender Updated my response based on your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @drescherjm suggested, something like this might work for you:

```
set(my_sources
    filea.cpp
    fileb.cpp
)
if(USE_MY)
    # Append filec if USE_MY is defined.
    set(my_sources ${my_sources} filec.cpp)
endif()
```

Similarly,

```
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/liba)
if(USE_MY)
    add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libb)
endif()
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libc

# ... other code here ...

# Link the libraries.
target_link_libraries(targetA ${my_liba} ${my_libc})
if(USE_MY)
    target_link_libraries(targetA ${my_libb})
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern CMake you'd do something like this:

```
add_subdirectory(my_stuff/liba)

if (USE_MY)
    add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libb)
endif()

add_subdirectory(my_stuff/libc
```

Then for sources:

```
add_library(libB source1.cpp source2.cpp source3.cpp)

if (USE_MY)
    target_sources(libB source4.cpp source5.cpp)
endif()
```